# Выбор на каком мониторе отображать интерфейс логина в ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, железо, bios

Видеокарта geforce 1070

- **hdmi** -> Основной монитор
- **dvi** -> Телик

По какой-то причине биос/ubunta считают главным монитором - телевизор, но когда осуществляется дальнейшая загрузка/вход в систему - он им быть перестаёт
Каким образом мне натравить пк на **hdmi** вход?

Comment: аcсоциация: https://askubuntu.com/questions/418607/dual-monitor-setup-grub-loader-goes-to-hdtv-even-if-it-is-turned-off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ответ на askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/347199/179720) и [на вики по арчу](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GDM#Setup_default_monitor_settings)

Настройте монитор как надо и скопируйте настройки на логин-скрин

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/
sudo chown gdm:gdm ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
```

С грабом сложнее. Он берет настройки с uefi. Можно покопаться в биосе. У меня есть настройка, чтоб изображение дублировалось на оба монитора.

Как вариант - поменять кабели местами, но придется купить переходник и dvi-hdmi кабель.

Comment: Ваш вариант решил мою проблему с выбором экрана логина, а вот с askubuntu с грабом не взлетел (видимо сделал что-то не совсем верно)
Хотя осталась проблема с тем, что видеокарта в приоритете видит tv как главный монитор и её решить, только взять переходник hdmi-dp, потому что подключая основной монитор не в hdmi - теряю рейт обновления в 144гц (dvi не вывозит). Как я нагуглил вчера - видеокарточка видит мониторы в порядке подключения слева направо, а слева у неё dvi
Спасибо!